# Magento2 : Additional images import programmatically

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, import

I'm trying to add additional images in products using custom script and below code i'm using. I have put product images in "additional_images" column of my csv and `$image_directory` is my path where product images put.

```
$filesystem = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Filesystem');
$mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
$mediaPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath();
$mainImage = $data['base_image'];


        $addimages = $data["additional_images"]; 

$addimagesData = explode(',',$addimages);
 foreach($addimagesData as $addimages_img){
 $image_directory = '/var/www/html/myproject/pub/media/import/'.$addimages_img;
 $product->addImageToMediaGallery($image_directory, null, false, false);//assigning image, thumb and small image to media gallery      
}
```

After run my script i'm getting below error. I have also set all permission for folder and images. Any help should be appreciated.

```
[Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException]
The file "/var/www/html/myproject/pub/media/tmp/catalog/product/p/o/powerhub-back.jpg" doe
sn't exist or not a file
```

Comment: Please anyone help me out from this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error when I was trying to import the main image and additional images together.So I import the main image and the added the additional images using the following code.

```
 $imgs = explode('|',$prodData[10]);

        if(sizeof($imgs) > 1) {

            $product = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($newProdId);
            $productRepository = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
            $productRepository->save($product);

            for ( $i=1; $i<sizeof($imgs); $i++ ) {

                echo 'Add Images :' . $prdbasepath.basename(trim($imgs[$i])) . PHP_EOL;
                $image_directory = $prdbasepath.'data'.DS.basename(trim($imgs[$i]));


                if (file_exists($image_directory) && getimagesize($image_directory)) {

                    echo 'File exists'.PHP_EOL;
                    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($image_directory, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
                    $product->save();

                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the image url, use magento tools. Because Magento will use the correct path.

```
<?php
namespace {Vendor}\{Module}\Helper;
    
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use SplFileInfo;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

class ProductImageHelper
{
  private Filesystem $filesystem;
  private ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository;

  public function __construct(
    Filesystem $filesystem,
    ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
  ) {
    $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
  }

  public function setProductImage($productId)
  {
    $mediapath = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath() . 'import';
    $fileInfo = new \SplFileInfo('file.jpg');
    $url = $mediapath . '/' . $fileInfo->getBaseName();

    $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
    $product->addImageToMediaGallery(
                                $url,
                                array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'),
                                false,
                                false
                            );
    $this->productRepository->save($product);

  }
}
```